# How to use string, switch, case and bufferedreader?

Tags: string, switch-statement, bufferedreader

I got question if how can i use the string, switch, case and the bufferedreader?
In my situation, the output should be ->

Choose your password:

A.Thepasskey

B.12345

C.54321

Then if i choose "thepasskey" it appears 
"the passkey you entered is thepasskey".
Then if i entered the wrong password that not on the choicelist, the appearance will be 
"error! Check your data!".
Can anybody answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Choose your password:");
    System.out.println("A. Thepasskey");
    System.out.println("B. 12345");
    System.out.println("C. 54321");
    String line = br.readLine();
    switch (line) {
        case "A"://if one type A as choice
            System.out.println("Thepasskey");
            break;
        case "B":
            System.out.println("12345");
            break;
        case "C":
            System.out.println("54321");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("error! Check your data");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that  the code that when i  entered "thepasskey" as a password,  it will appear?  It is doesn't need to used "int"?

Comment: I tried it  but  the system shown  the error  on 'case' and in the 'string'.

Comment: Here u can type your options as A or B or C all that ll be string not number

Comment: I mean when i type the word "thepasskey"  the appearance will be  "the password you choose is thepasskey"